# Count pages in PDF file using Imagemagick - PHP

Tags: php, pdf, imagemagick, imagick

I am using **PHP 5 with Apache** in my **Windows Vista PC**. I have `Imagemagick` already installed and configured. I want to count the total number of pages in a pdf file using `imagick`.

I fount one solution **[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1098156/number-of-pages-in-a-pdf-file)**, but dont know how to open pdf file as text and count pages.

**somebody give me a clear solution to count pages using imagemagick like**

**`identify -format %n testfile.pdf`**

From googling, I found some workarounds or examples;

1. `imagick(identify -format %n testfile.pdf)`
2. `identify -density 12 -format "%p" testfile.pdf`
3. `identify -format %n testfile.pdf`

I don't know how to make use of this stuff..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved it using;

`exec("identify -format %n $file")`

Comment: This will be *extremely* slow for multi-page PDFs, especially for ones with more complex graphics on the pages...

Answer (score 14):

Instead of using `"identify -format %n $file"`(which can turn out to be extremely slow for complex or for mult-page PDFs) you should rather use **the right tool for the job**, `pdfinfo`:

```
exec("pdfinfo $file | grep Pages: | awk '{print $2}'")
```

which is faster by several magnitudes...

Comment: Useful pointer, but I had some difficulty figuring out how to get pdfinfo in my systems. Finally: Debian/Ubuntu: sudo aptitude install poppler-utils; OSX: brew install poppler.

Answer (score -1):

From the [mentioned page](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.pdf.php), here is a sample code to get the page count:

```
<?php
public function getNumPagesInPDF(array $arguments = array())
{
@list($PDFPath) = $arguments;
$stream = @fopen($PDFPath, "r");
$PDFContent = @fread ($stream, filesize($PDFPath));
if(!$stream || !$PDFContent)
    return false;
$firstValue = 0;
$secondValue = 0;
if(preg_match("/\/N\s+([0-9]+)/", $PDFContent, $matches)) {
    $firstValue = $matches[1];
}
if(preg_match_all("/\/Count\s+([0-9]+)/s", $PDFContent, $matches))
{
    $secondValue = max($matches[1]);
}
return (($secondValue != 0) ? $secondValue : max($firstValue, $secondValue));
}
?>
```

Comment: this is not working for me.. :( I set $PDFPath = "test.pdf"; , but not working. What should I do?

Comment: This thread might help you then: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1143841/count-the-number-of-pages-in-a-pdf-in-only-php

Comment: This solution will work not in all cases. For me this script didn't work for PDF 1.6, but worked for 1.4 and 1.5 versions

Comment: the PDFlib library no longer maintained since 2010. But even worst, its commercial and not public domain.