# Get the number of pages in a PDF document

Tags: php, pdf

#### *This question is for referencing and comparing. The solution is [the accepted answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14644354/1062281).*

Many hours have I searched for a fast and easy, but mostly *accurate*, way to get the number of pages in a PDF document. Since I work for a graphic printing and reproduction company that works a lot with PDFs, the number of pages in a document must be precisely known before they are processed. PDF documents come from many different clients, so they aren't generated with the same application and/or don't use the same compression method.

Here are some of the answers I found ***insufficient*** or simply ***NOT working***:

### Using [Imagick](http://php.net/manual/en/book.imagick.php) (a PHP extension)

Imagick requires a lot of installation, apache needs to restart, and when I finally had it working, it took amazingly long to process (2-3 minutes per document) and it always returned `1` page in every document (haven't seen a working copy of Imagick so far), so I threw it away. That was with both the `getNumberImages()` and `identifyImage()` methods.

### Using [FPDI](http://www.setasign.de/products/pdf-php-solutions/fpdi/about/) (a PHP library)

FPDI is easy to use and install (just extract files and call a PHP script), **BUT** many of the compression techniques are not supported by FPDI. It then returns an error:

> FPDF error: This document (test_1.pdf) probably uses a compression technique which is not supported by the free parser shipped with FPDI.

### Opening a stream and search with a regular expression:

This opens the PDF file in a stream and searches for some kind of string, containing the pagecount or something similar.

```
$f = "test1.pdf";
$stream = fopen($f, "r");
$content = fread ($stream, filesize($f));

if(!$stream || !$content)
    return 0;

$count = 0;
// Regular Expressions found by Googling (all linked to SO answers):
$regex  = "/\/Count\s+(\d+)/";
$regex2 = "/\/Page\W*(\d+)/";
$regex3 = "/\/N\s+(\d+)/";

if(preg_match_all($regex, $content, $matches))
    $count = max($matches);

return $count;
```

- `/\/Count\s+(\d+)/` (looks for `/Count <number>`) doesn't work because only a few documents have the parameter `/Count` inside, so most of the time it doesn't return anything. [Source.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2314086/1062281)
- `/\/Page\W*(\d+)/` (looks for `/Page<number>`) doesn't get the number of pages, mostly contains some other data. [Source.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1536494/1062281)
- `/\/N\s+(\d+)/` (looks for `/N <number>`) doesn't work either, as the documents can contain multiple values of `/N` ; most, if not all, **not** containing the pagecount. [Source.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7462664/1062281)

---

> #### So, what does work reliable and accurate?
>
> [See the answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14644354/1062281)

Answer (score 114, accepted):

### A simple command line executable called: *pdfinfo*.

It is [downloadable for Linux and Windows](http://www.foolabs.com/xpdf/download.html). You download a compressed file containing several little PDF-related programs. Extract it somewhere.

One of those files is **pdfinfo** (or **pdfinfo.exe** for Windows). An example of data returned by running it on a PDF document:

```
Title:          test1.pdf
Author:         John Smith
Creator:        PScript5.dll Version 5.2.2
Producer:       Acrobat Distiller 9.2.0 (Windows)
CreationDate:   01/09/13 19:46:57
ModDate:        01/09/13 19:46:57
Tagged:         yes
Form:           none
Pages:          13    <-- This is what we need
Encrypted:      no
Page size:      2384 x 3370 pts (A0)
File size:      17569259 bytes
Optimized:      yes
PDF version:    1.6
```

I haven't seen a PDF document where it returned a false pagecount (yet). It is also really fast, even with big documents of 200+ MB the response time is a just a few seconds or less.

There is an easy way of extracting the pagecount from the output, here in PHP:

```php
// Make a function for convenience 
function getPDFPages($document)
{
    $cmd = "/path/to/pdfinfo";           // Linux
    $cmd = "C:\\path\\to\\pdfinfo.exe";  // Windows
    
    // Parse entire output
    // Surround with double quotes if file name has spaces
    exec("$cmd \"$document\"", $output);

    // Iterate through lines
    $pagecount = 0;
    foreach($output as $op)
    {
        // Extract the number
        if(preg_match("/Pages:\s*(\d+)/i", $op, $matches) === 1)
        {
            $pagecount = intval($matches[1]);
            break;
        }
    }
    
    return $pagecount;
}

// Use the function
echo getPDFPages("test 1.pdf");  // Output: 13
```

Of course this command line tool can be used in other languages that can parse output from an external program, but I use it in PHP.

**I know its not pure PHP**, but external programs are *way* better in PDF handling (as seen in the question).

I hope this can help people, because I have spent a whole lot of time trying to find the solution to this and I have seen a lot of questions about PDF pagecount in which I didn't find the answer I was looking for. That's why I made this question and answered it myself.

Security Notice: Use `escapeshellarg` on `$document` if document name is being fed from user input or file uploads.

Comment: +1 For taking time to help community and for sharing your knowledge gained as a result of this problem

Comment: As an alternative (if pdfinfo is not available on the server), you can also use **pdftk** with the `dump_data` option.

You just have to do a few changes : 
- Set the $cmd variable to the pdftk binary
- Change the preg_match call from `Pages` to `NumberOfPages`

And that's all :-)

Comment: @bouchon - It sure looks like something nice (the Server one that is, the rest has a GUI), although you have to install it. `pdfinfo` is a single binary file. Just download it and place it anywhere (e.g. next to your PHP script for easy access)

Comment: I make a composer package for this. Wish it can help
https://github.com/howtomakeaturn/pdfinfo

Comment: @尤川豪  Wow, that's really impressive! I'm honored :)

Comment: This can be done right in the shell using the usual gnu tools:

    pdfinfo $PDF_File | grep Pages | awk '{print $2}'

Comment: Any recommendation for Centos/Amazon Linux?  pdfinfo and xpdf don't seem to be available for this OS.

Comment: I found poppler.  sudo yum install poppler-utils and now I have pdfinfo in Amazon Linux on EC2

Comment: `mutool info` from the mupdf-tools package is significantly faster than `pdfinfo`.

Comment: pdfinfo is inside `sudo apt-get install poppler-utils` for the lazy ubuntu / lxss users

Comment: What if I need to get the number of pages of an online PDF without downloading it?

Comment: @f126ck well you need *some* way of reading the file. So I guess you could load it with `curl` or `wget` into a temp file and then execute that script on it

Comment: `pdfinfo` is definitively worth it to count pages against command line `gs` or npm packages like `pdf2json`. Its output is immediate compared to others that take several seconds for large files. Thank you!

Comment: I can only recommend `qpdf`, because qpdf returns json or pure values, and you save yourself the parsing. This is not only faster but also less code.

Comment: Be aware that `pdfinfo` (and all of `poppler-utils`) is licensed under `GPL`.
https://www.glyphandcog.com/opensource.html

Answer (score 32):

Simplest of all is using **ImageMagick**

here is a sample code

```
$image = new Imagick();
$image->pingImage('myPdfFile.pdf');
echo $image->getNumberImages();
```

otherwise you can also use `PDF` libraries like `MPDF` or `TCPDF` for `PHP`

Comment: Brilliant, thank you, just something to note though, not all PHP installations have the imagick mod installed... you may need to check if that class exists first.

Comment: i found this worked at first, but then some PDFs gave an error of 'Failed to read the file' presumably they were not compatible.  Suggest using the library  noted above: https://github.com/howtomakeaturn/pdfinfo

Comment: Imagick::pingImage not implemented
im getting an error like this

Answer (score 11):

You can use `qpdf` like below. If a file file_name.pdf has 100 pages,

```
$ qpdf --show-npages file_name.pdf
100
```

Comment: +1 One of the few options that is not licensed under GPL:
http://qpdf.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 6):

Here is a simple example to get the number of pages in PDF with PHP.

```
<?php

function count_pdf_pages($pdfname) {
  $pdftext = file_get_contents($pdfname);
  $num = preg_match_all("/\/Page\W/", $pdftext, $dummy);

  return $num;
}

$pdfname = 'example.pdf'; // Put your PDF path
$pages = count_pdf_pages($pdfname);

echo $pages;

?>
```

Comment: In case of PDFs without incremental updates this may often work.

Comment: Can confirm this works on many occasions. But recently i ran into problems with PDF's consisting of more that 150 pages. E.g for a 179 page PDF, this counts for 181. Other than that, simple and useful.

Comment: The reason for the extra pages is likely pdfmarks for Bookmarks. See the bookmarks section of the [Adobe pdfmarks reference](https://opensource.adobe.com/dc-acrobat-sdk-docs/acrobatsdk/pdfs/acrobatsdk_pdfmark.pdf)

Answer (score 3):

if you can't install any additional packages, you can use this simple one-liner:

```
foundPages=$(strings < $PDF_FILE | sed -n 's|.*Count -\{0,1\}\([0-9]\{1,\}\).*|\1|p' | sort -rn | head -n 1)
```

Comment: Could you explain what it does and needs? What is `sed -n`, `sort -rn` and `head -n`? Also it seems that you are looking for `/Count <number>`, which I showed in my question, doesn't work.

Comment: strings - grabs all strings from PDF binary.  Sed - matches values found in 'Count' strings. The (-n) when used in conjunction with (p)rint will avoid repetition of line printing.  sort - will take found 'Count' values and sort in (-r)everse order, handling each as a (n)umbers (descending).  head - will print first -n line numbers. In this case, 1 (default is 10), which will be the highest 'Count' value.  I haven't run across any PDFs that haven't had a Count value. Just luck I guess.  Have you verified that your regex is working properly outside of preg_match_all?

Comment: Thank you for your explanation. Yes I have. I have tested a lot of PDFs for this (as I'm mainly working with PDFs, like 100/day) and approx. 40% of all PDFs actually have the `Count` value. I've also tested this by simply writing the stream to a textfile and search for it (or even parts of it) manually. On some PDFs I've found it, but on most PDFs I didn't.

Answer (score 2):

This seems to work pretty well, without the need for special packages or parsing command output.

```
<?php                                                                               

$target_pdf = "multi-page-test.pdf";                                                
$cmd = sprintf("identify %s", $target_pdf);                                         
exec($cmd, $output);                                                                
$pages = count($output);
```

Comment: Running this commande returns me the followig `identify-im6.q16: attempt to perform an operation not allowed by the security policy PDF @ error/constitute.c/IsCoderAuthorized/408.` !

Answer (score 2):

Since you're ok with using command line utilities, you can use  [cpdf](https://github.com/coherentgraphics/cpdflib-binary) (Microsoft Windows/Linux/Mac OS X). To obtain the number of pages in one PDF:

```
cpdf.exe -pages "my file.pdf"
```

Answer (score 2):

I created a wrapper class for pdfinfo in case it's useful to anyone, based on Richard's answer@

```
/**
 * Wrapper for pdfinfo program, part of xpdf bundle
 * http://www.xpdfreader.com/about.html
 * 
 * this will put all pdfinfo output into keyed array, then make them accessible via getValue
 */
class PDFInfoWrapper {

    const PDFINFO_CMD = 'pdfinfo';

    /**
     * keyed array to hold all the info
     */
    protected $info = array();

    /**
     * raw output in case we need it
     */
    public $raw = "";

    /**
     * Constructor
     * @param string $filePath - path to file
     */
    public function __construct($filePath) {
        exec(self::PDFINFO_CMD . ' "' . $filePath . '"', $output);

        //loop each line and split into key and value
        foreach($output as $line) {
            $colon = strpos($line, ':');
            if($colon) {
                $key = trim(substr($line, 0, $colon));
                $val = trim(substr($line, $colon + 1));

                //use strtolower to make case insensitive
                $this->info[strtolower($key)] = $val;
            }
        }

        //store the raw output
        $this->raw = implode("\n", $output);

    }

    /**
     * get a value
     * @param string $key - key name, case insensitive
     * @returns string value
     */
    public function getValue($key) {
        return @$this->info[strtolower($key)];
    }

    /**
     * list all the keys
     * @returns array of key names
     */
    public function getAllKeys() {
        return array_keys($this->info);
    }

}
```

Comment: Thinking about this, for security a check that $filePath is valid (i.e. `if(!file_exists($filePath)) return false`) prior to calling exec() should probably be added

Comment: james well said, I would use is_readable instead of file_exists though :) Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I got problems with imagemagick installations on production server. After hours of attempts, I decided to get rid of IM, and found another approach:

Install poppler-utils:

```
$ sudo apt install poppler-utils     [On Debian/Ubuntu & Mint]
$ sudo dnf install poppler-utils     [On RHEL/CentOS & Fedora]
$ sudo zypper install poppler-tools  [On OpenSUSE]  
$ sudo pacman -S poppler             [On Arch Linux]
```

Then execute via shell in your PL ( e.g. PHP):

```
shell_exec("pdfinfo $filePath | grep Pages | cut -f 2 -d':' | xargs");
```

Answer (score 1):

this simple 1 liner seems to do the job well:

`strings $path_to_pdf | grep Kids | grep -o R | wc -l`

there is a block in the PDF file which details the number of pages in this funky string:

`/Kids [3 0 R 4 0 R 5 0 R 6 0 R 7 0 R 8 0 R 9 0 R 10 0 R 11 0 R 12 0 R 13 0 R 14 0 R 15 0 R 16 0 R 17 0 R 18 0 R 19 0 R 20 0 R 21 0 R 22 0 R 23 0 R 24 0 R 25 0 R 26 0 R 27 0 R 28 0 R 29 0 R 30 0 R 31 0 R 32 0 R 33 0 R 34 0 R 35 0 R 36 0 R 37 0 R 38 0 R 39 0 R 40 0 R 41 0 R]`

The number of 'R' characters is the number of pages

[screenshot of terminal showing output from strings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JcLKc.png)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `mutool`.

```bash
mutool show FILE.pdf trailer/Root/Pages/Count
```

`mutool` is part of the [MuPDF](https://mupdf.com/) software package.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a `R` function that reports the PDF file page number by using the `pdfinfo` command.

```
pdf.file.page.number <- function(fname) {
    a <- pipe(paste("pdfinfo", fname, "| grep Pages | cut -d: -f2"))
    page.number <- as.numeric(readLines(a))
    close(a)
    page.number
}
if (F) {
    pdf.file.page.number("a.pdf")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a Windows command script using gsscript that reports the PDF file page number

```
@echo off
echo.
rem
rem this file: getlastpagenumber.cmd
rem version 0.1 from commander 2015-11-03
rem need Ghostscript e.g. download and install from http://www.ghostscript.com/download/
rem Install path "C:\prg\ghostscript" for using the script without changes \\ and have less problems with UAC
rem

:vars
  set __gs__="C:\prg\ghostscript\bin\gswin64c.exe"
  set __lastpagenumber__=1
  set __pdffile__="%~1"
  set __pdffilename__="%~n1"
  set __datetime__=%date%%time%
  set __datetime__=%__datetime__:.=%
  set __datetime__=%__datetime__::=%
  set __datetime__=%__datetime__:,=%
  set __datetime__=%__datetime__:/=% 
  set __datetime__=%__datetime__: =% 
  set __tmpfile__="%tmp%\%~n0_%__datetime__%.tmp"

:check
  if %__pdffile__%=="" goto error1
  if not exist %__pdffile__% goto error2
  if not exist %__gs__% goto error3

:main
  %__gs__% -dBATCH -dFirstPage=9999999 -dQUIET -dNODISPLAY -dNOPAUSE  -sstdout=%__tmpfile__%  %__pdffile__%
  FOR /F " tokens=2,3* usebackq delims=:" %%A IN (`findstr /i "number" test.txt`) DO set __lastpagenumber__=%%A 
  set __lastpagenumber__=%__lastpagenumber__: =%
  if exist %__tmpfile__% del %__tmpfile__%

:output
  echo The PDF-File: %__pdffilename__% contains %__lastpagenumber__% pages
  goto end

:error1
  echo no pdf file selected
  echo usage: %~n0 PDFFILE
  goto end

:error2
  echo no pdf file found
  echo usage: %~n0 PDFFILE
  goto end

:error3
  echo.can not find the ghostscript bin file
  echo.   %__gs__%
  echo.please download it from:
  echo.   http://www.ghostscript.com/download/
  echo.and install to "C:\prg\ghostscript"
  goto end

:end
  exit /b
```

Answer (score 0):

The R package [pdftools](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/pdftools/pdftools.pdf) and the function `pdf_info()` provides information on the number of pages in a pdf.

```
library(pdftools)
pdf_file <- file.path(R.home("doc"), "NEWS.pdf")
info <- pdf_info(pdf_file)
nbpages <- info[2]
nbpages

$pages
[1] 65
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to shell, a simplest (but not usable on 100% of PDFs) approach would be to use `grep`.

This should return just the number of pages:

```
grep -m 1 -aoP '(?<=\/N )\d+(?=\/)' file.pdf
```

Example: https://regex101.com/r/BrUTKn/1

Switches description:

- `-m 1` is neccessary as some files can have more than one match of regex pattern *(volonteer needed to replace this with match-only-first regex solution extension)*
- `-a` is neccessary to treat the binary file as text
- `-o` to show only the match
- `-P` to use Perl regular expression

Regex explanation:

- starting "delimiter": `(?<=\/N )` lookbehind of `/N` (nb. space character not seen here)
- actual result: `\d+` any number of digits
- ending "delimiter": `(?=\/)` lookahead of `/`

Nota bene: if in some case match is not found, it's safe to assume only 1 page exists.

Answer (score 0):

This works fine in Imagemagick.

`convert image.pdf -format "%n\n" info: | head -n 1`

Answer (score -1):

Often you read regex `/\/Page\W/` but it won't work for me for several pdf files.
So here is an other regex expression, that works for me.

```
$pdf = file_get_contents($path_pdf);
return preg_match_all("/[<|>][\r\n|\r|\n]*\/Type\s*\/Page\W/", $path_pdf, $dummy);
```