# How to get a page count in an mPDF document?

Tags: php, mpdf

Does anybody knows how to get the number of generated pages if a PDF document using mPDF library?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1098156/number-of-pages-in-a-pdf-file - may helps you

Comment: add this to a main mPDF class:

    function getPageCount() {
     return count($this->pages);
    }

then add a html-parser such string:

    $html = str_replace('{PAGECNT}', $this->getPageCount(), $html);

after these actions you can insert {PAGECNT} directly in your parsed HTML to get the result. This is useful is you need to indicate a page, like: "page 2 of 5".

Answer (score 8, accepted):

add this to a main mPDF class:

```
function getPageCount() {
    return count($this->pages);
}
```

then add a html-parser such string:

```
$html = str_replace('{PAGECNT}', $this->getPageCount(), $html);
```

after these actions you can insert {PAGECNT} directly in your parsed HTML to get the result. This is useful is you need to indicate a page:

Comment: This works for me but only shows on the last page, is it possible to show in the footer of every page?

Comment: tell pleaze where need insert parse html? in what function?

Comment: @VincePettit ..how to create a html based index in mpdf

Answer (score 32):

I was looking for the same functionallity while using EYiiPdf (a wrapper for mPDF on Yii) and the following worked like a charm:

```
$mPDF->setFooter('{PAGENO} / {nb}');
```

I checked mPDF's source and found this at mpdf.php:1656 (version 5.4):

```
function AliasNbPages($alias='{nb}') {
    //Define an alias for total number of pages
    $this->aliasNbPg=$alias;
}
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Actually accepted answer dint work for me!! And your solution worked out :)

Comment: i'am creating pdfs using mpdf(inside Yii), pdfs are created from htmls, and i used setfooter to the footer stuff, but its getting displayed in last page only!
how to get that in every page?
$mPDF1->setFooter('{DATE j-m-Y}|{PAGENO}/{nb}','O|E');

Answer (score 19):

You can use **{nbpg}**, like

```
<div align="center"><b>{PAGENO} / {nbpg}</b></div>
```

Comment: This is a very useful answer. If you are using `resetpagenum`, `{nbpg}`shows the current page number counting from your last reset. If you want to show the total page count, you can use `{nb}`.

Answer (score 10):

If you are trying to return the number of pages so you can save this to a database or some other operation outside of mpdf it's easy to pull it this way.

After you write your content:

```
$mpdf->WriteHTML($html);
$page_count = $mpdf -> page;

$mpdf->Output();
```

Comment: I've been looking for this for AGES, looking through the docs for hours and I've finally found the answer. Thank you so much!

Comment: Couldn't find this anywhere else! Thank you!

Answer (score 5):

- replacement aliases **{nb}** and **{nbpg}** for total number
- **{PAGENO}** for current page number

**UPDATE**

Please note, this answer refers to mdf library v4, which was a current version at the time of writing.

Minimum Working Example by @aiao

```
<?php 
$pagenumber= '<!--mpdf Page {PAGENO} of {nbpg}mpdf--> $mpdf->WriteHTML($pagenumber); 
$mpdf->Output();
?> 

<?php 
$pagenumber= '<!--mpdf Page {PAGENO} of {nbpg}mpdf--> $mpdf->WriteHTML($pagenumber); 
$mpdf->Output();
?>
```

Comment: Please explain how that should be used. How do they return a page count to the application?

Comment: Even though I can answer **your question**, the OP's question has nothing to do with returning the number of pages into application. Those are **replacement aliases**, they are put into your html template and parsed by the mdf class instance. This is an answer for library v4, if I remember correctly, please see the year. The documentation for this library was missing (maybe still is), making it difficult to find the right placeholder names right away.

Comment: Please include a MWE (Minimum Working Example). You don't have to test it, although it would be nice.... instantiate an object, use the paramter ..etc <?php
$pagenumber= '<!--mpdf Page {PAGENO} of {nbpg}mpdf--> $mpdf->WriteHTML($pagenumber); $mpdf->Output();?>

Comment: @aiao Actually, feel free to edit my answer.  I wrote that answer because I had to spend some time myself finding those placeholders (In fact I didn't know they existed from the start ). IMHO, if the OP got to the point of asking this question, he knows pretty well how to init the library and create a basic pdf from html. The last version I worked with was 6, there's probably newer version out there now. I don't think we should spend so much time improving this answer.

Answer (score 0):

Watch for the line:

`preg_replace('/\{DATE\s+(.*?)\}/e',"date('\\1')",$hd);`

in mpdf.php function Footer()
It may cause your "{PAGENO} / {nb}" to not be displayed.
Just comment it out or use `strpos('{DATE' > -1)` to check if it is available.
Also you may need to add:

`$mpdf->ignore_invalid_utf8 = true;`

and also if you don't want footer line:

```
$mpdf->defaultfooterline = false;
```

After these changes the pagination worked for me at last.