# Can I save number of pages into a variable in back-end from mPDF?

Tags: php, pdf, backend, mpdf

I'm trying to get mPDF number of pages to be saved in a php variable.

```
$mpdf->setHeader({"nb"});
```

Is there a way to get the value this outputs in php.

I want to save it in a variable.

Comment: Did you check [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10280595/how-to-get-a-page-count-in-an-mpdf-document)

Comment: First I needed the page number, So I could make a barcode out of it. I managed to do that. The problem was I was trying to make the number four digits, using str_pad() which did not work because the number is given when the document gets compiled.

Answer (score 0):

I realized {nb} cannot be modified with php because it gets its value when the pdf gets compiled.